# How to lift a roof using no electricity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

I constructed a small building to protect irrigation valves from freezing. The roof is hinged and rests at a 110 degree angle. The goal is to lift it up to about 20 degrees. The roof is 4'x 8', and weighs 100#. I want counter balance the lid to assist in lifting. The hard part is the lift mechanism needs to be hidden inside.

My idea for lift is to mount a bar to lid and mount a bar to the building base, then connect the two rods, and have all 3 connection points hinged. Then use pulley's and a counter weight to pull the bars to near vertical alignment. So the bars will be in a tight v position when lid is closed. As lid opens the v would get larger until bars are almost I vertical alignment.

How could I improve this design?

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your situation (roof at 110°, lift it to 20°?), could you please [edit] your question with a sketch?

Comment: I was using degrees to illustrate the range of motion needed. Does this picture help?

Comment: I had a hard time to fix your complete lack of capital case.

Comment: Levers.  They can do anything.

Comment: Meanwhile-- if that small of a roof weighs that much, you built it wrong. try replacing it with a thin sheet of (shingled) plywood and adding a few stringers to brace it. You should be able to get under 30 pounds.

Comment: Weight is a guess.  The roof is 1/2 pressure treated exterior plywood with felt paper and cedar shingles.  Shingles are wet from winter, it should weigh less in summer

Comment: And the roof is built differently than you would have built it.  NOT built wrong

Comment: Have you considered using door openers? There are a variety of mechanical door openers available. You can try searching for them on the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Try looking into gas spring based door openers and hatch lifts. They are commonly available for various weights, and can easily be installed hidden inside the building.

[image: door opener]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[image]

The lifting arm would need to be assisted by something like spring struts (e.g. car tailgate/hood lifters) between the floor/back wall and the lid.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested, gas springs are probably the way to go here, they are available in a wide range of stroke length, spring force and attachment methods. I have the most experience with products from [Suspa](https://www.suspa.com/us/products/gas-springs/) here in the USA, but there are hundreds of manufacturers world wide.

Make sure you get a gas **spring** and not a gas strut or a gas damper, they are not the same despite similar appearances. Don't be like me and have to learn this the hard way.

Size the spring and select your mounting points such that the force of the spring offsets about 90% of the lid's weight. For your application, assuming that you'd use two springs, one on each side, I would look into a locking gas spring  on on side so that the lid stays in place once it is in the fully open position.

Comment: I did some looking around at gas Springs and the issue I ran into is the weight of the door.  The springs that have enough strength to lift the door, could potentially make it difficult to close the door?

Comment: Potentially, yes. But gas springs come in such a wide variety of stroke lengths and force that you can design your mounting points so that the spring provides enough lift that the door's apparent weight is 5-10lb throughout the angle of movement. If you do the design properly, the door should NOT stay open with just the springs thus the need for the locking spring. I have done this many times designing the opening mechanism for truck hoods weighing 200+lb.

Comment: Keep in mind that a gas spring, unlike a conventional spring, provides a nearly constant force over its entire stroke.

Comment: Very cool,  I need to figure out the exact weight that needs to be lifted.  But this would very compact and easy to hide.   Thankyou for your input

Comment: I underestimated the gas spring

Comment: @Tadhenley the fourbar you had in your picture will help with choosing of the spring.